# Is creating/saving 100 images to hard disk vs USB Flash Drive a fair test to test write speed?

Tags: c#, .net, image, file-io, io

I am writing some code to create a Bitmap, do some drawing and then saving to file.  Below is a simplified version:

```
FinalImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(FinalImageWidth, FinalImageHeight);
Pencil = Graphics.FromImage(FinalImage);
Pencil.Clear(Color.White);
Pencil.DrawImage(image,x,y);
FinalImage.Save(FinalImageSaveLocation + "test" + Counter + ".bmp");
```

This is fine.

Out of interest I timed this creation process over 100 times writing to C:\ and it came up as 2secs, I then plugged in a USB Pen drive and wrote 100 image to that and it took 5.5secs.

I thought flash drives were faster although I know different pen drives have different capabilities and guess there is on-board USB controllers and Cache to take into account.  Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Solid state drives I believe would be faster as hard disks, however in my experience USB memory sticks have always been slower than a normal hard drive. I haven't got figures in front of me for these things and my anecdotal experience is from some years back so may be out of date.

Comment: Not a fair test.  My solid state drive runs on a SATA 3 internal connection, with I expect far supreme read/write IO speeds to the flash disk you used.  The flash drives of course will only use the USB bus available, which won't compare to SATA speeds.

Comment: In addition (and without trying to boast - much) I installed Windows to a SATA 3 connected SSD last week.  The entire install took around 3 minutes including 2 reboots.  I would expect a normal HDD to take up to 20 minutes, and had I tried to install to a flash disk somehow, it to take much *much* longer

Comment: WOW! Where did you install it from? Optical, external HDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a relative test between two filesystems, that should be fine.  As for why the USB drive appears to be slower there could be a number of reasons.  Perhaps that particular drive uses slower flash memory.  Perhaps the USB interface is only running at 12 Mbps ("Full Speed") instead of at USB 2.0 speeds.  Perhaps the OS is using an in-memory write-back cache for the HDD that is preventing you from seeing the actual performance of the disk.

As a benchmark of absolute write speed, however, your test may not be very accurate.  Creating and drawing a bitmapped image in memory is a CPU and memory-intensive task, and so your absolute performance values may be skewed by the performance (or lack thereof) of the processor and memory subsystems, causing inconsistent results across multiple platforms.  A slightly better approach might be to zero-out a 1 KB block of memory, open a random file on the device you want to test, and then time how long it takes to write your 1 KB block 10,000 times to that device.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison is valid in terms of the speed of writing data to these devices. However the differences are likely to be because of the hardware variations. The USB bus may not be as quick as the bus to the hard drive, which will slow it down. Also if you pen was filling up and you hard drive wasn't that would make a difference as the file would be fragmented.

So they probably reflect the time it would take to save files form your computer onto them. But they cannot be used as an absolute test of disk performance.

Caching ( as someone else said ) is also significant.